# Sorting String[] with Dates

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, date

I desperately try to sort an array with date e.g. "31.05.2019". I'm currently trying to do this by converting to a date type and then back. This also works. I just can't convert the string[] to Date[]. Can somebody tell me how to do it? or if necessary, give me an easier way to sort it? Unfortunately, I haven't found anything suitable online. It can also be that I'm too stupid.

I tried to convert the String manually to Date and it works. But i tried different ways to convert String[] to Date[]. I tried with a loop.. and some other stuff... but it doesnt work..

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    TagebuchIO io = new TagebuchIO();
    String[] stringio = io.getTagebuchliste();
    //He got the Dates with stringio
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyy");

    Date date = sdf.parse("10.05.2010");
    Date date2 = sdf.parse("09.02.2012");
    Date[] d = {date, date2};
    Arrays.sort(d);
    String ergbenis1 = sdf.format(d[0]);
    System.out.println(ergbenis1);
    ergbenis1 = sdf.format(d[1]);
    System.out.println(ergbenis1);
}
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: You simply should not keep your dates as an array of `String`. Use an array of `LocalDate` (from java.time) throughout. When you receive string input, parse it into `LocalDate` first thing. Only format back to `String` when you need to give output. It will give you a clear separation of model and interface (look up MVC) and will in the end be simpler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using `LocalDate` rather than `Date`:

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");

    String[] strDates = new String[] {"12.06.2019", "31.05.2019", "10.05.2010", "09.02.2012"};
    LocalDate[] dates = Stream.of(strDates).map(date -> LocalDate.parse(date, formatter))
                                           .toArray(LocalDate[]::new);

    System.out.println(String.format("Unsorted dates: %s", Arrays.toString(dates)));
    Arrays.sort(dates);
    System.out.println(String.format("Sorted dates: %s", Arrays.toString(dates)));

    System.out.println("Formatted Dates:");
    for (LocalDate d : dates) {
      System.out.println(formatter.format(d));
    }
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Unsorted dates: [2019-06-12, 2019-05-31, 2010-05-10, 2012-02-09]
Sorted dates: [2010-05-10, 2012-02-09, 2019-05-31, 2019-06-12]
Formatted Dates:
10.05.2010
09.02.2012
31.05.2019
12.06.2019
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm just wondering how you're supposed to figure that out... :D Has already helped me a lot. But what would it look like, if the conversion should not be displayed the other way around at the end and with a dot instead of a dash?

Comment: You can use the `DateTimeFormatter` on each `LocalDate` to get your desired output format, don't convert it back to a `String[]`

Answer (score 1):

You can convert String[] to Dates[] using the following :

```
Date[] d = new Date[args.length];
for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    d[i] = sdf.parse(dates[i]);
}
```

You can the sort the the Date[] array d as following :

```
Arrays.sort(d);
```

And then modify the String[] array as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    args[i] = sdf.format(d[i]);
}
```

I think this is acceptable solution. Are you looking for something else?

Answer (score 0):

Following pseudo code might help

```
ArrayList<String> dateStrings = new ArrayList<>(  );
    [...]
List<LocalDate> dates = dateStrings.stream()
            .map( LocalDate::parse )
            .collect( Collectors.toList() );
dates.sort();
```